# Delete unique index mssql

Tags: sql-server

I have a table having email as unique key constraint. I want to drop it, How it will possible?

Tried : `DROP INDEX email_2 ON users;`

No luck

```
    An explicit `DROP INDEX` is not allowed on index 'users.email_2'. 
It is being used for `UNIQUE KEY` constraint enforcement.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove it by dropping constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE users
DROP CONSTRAINT email_2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to drop the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE users DROP CONSTRAINT yourConstraint
```

Answer (score 0):

My research followed, I hope this help

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TAB1]') AND type in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[TAB1]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TAB1](
                [PAR1] [int] NOT NULL,
                [PAR2] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [IDX_PAR1] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
    [PAR1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TAB1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PAR2_CONSTRAINT]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [PAR2]
GO

-- forbidden
-- DROP INDEX TAB1.IDX_PAR1

-- should be
ALTER TABLE TAB1 DROP CONSTRAINT IDX_PAR1
```